# What exactly happens at this moment and how does it impact the New 52 universe?

Tags: dc, comics, the-new-52

In Red Hood and the Outlaws #27, we see something happening to Essence, Ducra's daughter (her death ?).

In [this particular panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eERQ.jpg), we see her "death" or whatever is happening to her being felt by major characters related to magic in the DC New 52 Universe : Constantine, Apollo, a big space guy I don't know, Trigon and Madame Xanadu.

All of them seem stunned or not understanding what is exactly happening.

So, what is happening at this moment and how is this a major event for the magic-related part of the universe ?